# Using group_by() to collapse a dataset in R based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, mutate

I am trying to collapse a dataset based on conditions and groupings from another dataset.
My current dataframe looks like this

For every 'RollNo' in every 'congress' I want a new variable indicating if the two senators in the same state voted together (1,0) and are in the same party (1,0)

| congress | sen | RollNo | state | Vote | Party |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | Jay | 1 | Ark | 1 | Rep |
| 106 | Mary | 1 | Ark | 1 | Dem |
| 106 | Bill | 2 | Ten | 2 | Dem |
| 106 | Kevin | 2 | Ten | 1 | Dem |
| 108 | Sue | 1 | Ore | 2 | Rep |
| 108 | Sally | 1 | Ore | 2 | Rep |
| 108 | Lisa | 3 | SDak | 1 | Rep |
| 108 | Penny | 3 | SDak | 2 | Rep |
| 109 | Jay | 1 | Mich | 1 | Dem |
| 109 | Mary | 1 | Mich | 9 | Rep |
| 109 | Rudy | 5 | Cal | 1 | Dem |
| 109 | Niles | 5 | Cal | 1 | Dem |

The new dataframe should look like this:

| congress | RollNo | state | Pair_Vote | Pair_Party |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | 1 | Ark | 1 | 0 |
| 106 | 2 | Ten | 0 | 1 |
| 108 | 1 | Ore | 1 | 1 |
| 108 | 3 | SDak | 0 | 1 |
| 109 | 1 | Mich | 0 | 0 |
| 109 | 5 | Cal | 1 | 1 |

I have tried the code below, tweaked it several times. My my dataset returns with the same observation and two new columns empty vectors for my new variables.

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe['Pair_Vote'] <- NA
dataframe['Pair_Party'] <- NA
newdata <- dataframe %>% group_by(congress, RollNo, state) %>% 
  mutate(Pair_Vote - case_when(any(Vote == Vote) ~ 1, FALSE ~ 0))
```

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mutate` when you want to add columns to a data frame as-is, use `summarize` when you want the result to have one row per group. Your output has one row per group, so we will use `summarize`.

And `vote == vote` won't do much useful, let's use `n_distinct` to count distinct values.

```
dataframe %>% 
  group_by(congress, RollNo, state) %>% 
  summarize(
    Pair_Vote = ifelse(n_distinct(Vote) == 1, 1, 0),
    Pair_Party = ifelse(n_distinct(Party) == 1, 1, 0)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `across` to modify multiple columns at once

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>%
    group_by(congress, RollNo, state) %>%
    summarise(across(c(Vote, Party),
       ~ +(n_distinct(.x) == 1), .names = "Pair_{.col}"), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  congress RollNo state Pair_Vote Pair_Party
     <int>  <int> <chr>     <int>      <int>
1      106      1 Ark           1          0
2      106      2 Ten           0          1
3      108      1 Ore           1          1
4      108      3 SDak          0          1
5      109      1 Mich          0          0
6      109      5 Cal           1          1
```

#### data

```
dataframe <- structure(list(congress = c(106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 108L, 108L, 
108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L), sen = c("Jay", "Mary", "Bill", 
"Kevin", "Sue", "Sally", "Lisa", "Penny", "Jay", "Mary", "Rudy", 
"Niles"), RollNo = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 5L), state = c("Ark", "Ark", "Ten", "Ten", "Ore", "Ore", 
"SDak", "SDak", "Mich", "Mich", "Cal", "Cal"), Vote = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L), Party = c("Rep", "Dem", 
"Dem", "Dem", "Rep", "Rep", "Rep", "Rep", "Dem", "Rep", "Dem", 
"Dem")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```